# What is needed to become a robotic team/startup leader?

Tags: product-management, technical-leader

Let's consider we want to create a complete robot like Nao(or even ASIMO), that has intelligence(machine vision, speech recognition), and robust electronics/mechanics parts. And we know each of these fields are a special expertise. Even I think in AI field for example, machine vision and speech recognition are two separate professions!

So, maybe it's impossible to consider someone is expert in all of them! It seems a person can only be an expert in only one of them(maybe two?!).

MY MAIN QUESTION: Considering what I said above, WHO CAN BECOME A LEADER OF A TEAM/STARTUP TO BUILD SUCH GREAT ROBOT? I mean what knowledge/skills should he/she has?

Also, what is the least team member requirements to create such product? I mean what people with what knowledge/skills are needed to become a part of that team?

Answer (score 2):

I work in a company doing AI, I can share with you some of the books that are influential for the work we do, but I think the best recommendation is to get real world experience on into this environment even by joining events, attending talks, etc.

Knowledge and skills:

- Understand very well AI and it’s implications in the future. (Some good books are [The technological singularity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262527804), [Rise of the Robots: Technology and the Threat of a Jobless Future](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465097537) )
- Technical expertise in coding. Someone who has decent coding skills and general knowledge about the implications of software related projects. [Managing the unmanageable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032182203X) explains a bit more why this is important, but basically it’s going to be very hard for a skilled creative team to be influenced by a leader who doesn’t understands high level how things work and why certain technical aspects are important
- Business skills and knowledge about how organisations work ([The lean startup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307887898), [The hard thing about hard things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062273205) and [How Google works](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1455582328))
- Negotiation skills (I like the book [Getting more](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Getting-More-Youre-always-negotiating/dp/0141049944) and in general soft skills… they explain the importance also in How Google works and managing the unmanageable)

Regarding the team required, is really hard to tell without a longer description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and links. But as you know, even in AI field, there is a vast field. Someone who works on CMUsphix project can say I work on AI field, and other one who works on OpenCV can say the same as well as another guy who works on data mining and big data related projects on web. Then when we talk about robotics, the area increases more and we should consider other fields like mechanical and electronics engineering as well. So, WHO can manage this bunch of experts in (maybe) completely different fields?

Comment: Even if we forget robotics and narrow the field on AI, in AI field there is different areas from vision to speech or data, and I think someone can't be expert or even experienced on all of them! So what happens for the fields you have no experienced on them? I mean if I am a Vision expert, but we have a project that has speech and NLP part as well, and I have no experience and maybe even no idea about that part of the project, so how can lead the whole team, specially the guys who are working on speech field?

Comment: And the question becomes more harder to answer when we like to become the leader of a robotic team that has mechanical and electronics engineers as well!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what's you actual concern? I got the feeling that you think that the leader should be an expert in everything?

I can also tell you that all of them have a common ground on coding and also that AI has a well defined core in statistics/computer science that I would consider enough to help you lead the team.

Remember that in general, great leaders are good at 3 things: soft skills, adapting skills and technical skills ;)

Comment: I am a graduated computer science in AI. Also because of my interests on robots, I created some MVP of my robots lonely. So because of this, I learned how to design with SolidWorks or Altium designer. And I know I am expert in non of them and there are many more skilled men than me even in computer science!

Beside that, I have no team work experience. I did what I did since now completely alone! But as you know, it's impossible(or has not rational reason) to make everything alone! So I decided to create a team and started to ask questions like this here, to understand how should I start?